# IIS7 Windows Authentication Providers

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, iis-7, authentication, kerberos, ntlm

Does anyone know what the different windows authentication providers for IIS7 means. There are 3 available providers

1. NTLM
2. Negotiate
3. Negotiate:Kerberos

NTLM is pretty obvious I think its NTLM and Negotiate is that Kerberos if so then what is Negotiate:Kerberos ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you are seeing is actually a new feature in Windows Server 2008 R2.

NTLM and Negotiate are the same as the were in older versions of IIS. You are correct that Negotiate = Kerberos for the purposes of this discussion - but Negotiate can also fall back to NTLM if it cannot authenticate using Kerberos.

2008 R2 added a new feature in IIS called "[Negotiable 2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771945.aspx)" (called Nego2 a lot in documentation/blogs) which allows new authentication providers like LiveID to work with IIS.

One of the additional benefits of Nego2 is that it allows you to have a Kerberos/Negotiate authentication provider that does not fall back to NTLM if it can't authenticate. That is the new "Negotiate:Kerberos" provider you are seeing.

The downside of this is that to use Nego2 providers (including Negotiate:Kerberos) you must disable kernel-mode authentication, which can decrease performance and cause other problems depending on your configuration.

Comment: Official source: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2008-R2-and-2008/cc771945(v=ws.11)